# The dynamically created components in vue.js shows random behaviour

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

What i want is, there a list made from json data. When i click on a item, it creates a new list dynamically.
Now when i click a different item in the first list, i want the second list to change depending on data i receive.

html structure is :

```
div class="subject-list container-list" id="app-1">
    <item-subject
         v-for="item in subjectlist"
         v-bind:item="item"
         v-bind:key="item.id"
         >
    </item-subject>
</div>

//some other code


<div class="exam-list container-list" id="app-2">
    <item-exam
     v-for="item in examlist"
     v-bind:item="item"
     v-bind:key="item.id"
     >
    </item-exam>

</div>
```

The main.js file is :

```
//Dummy json data
var subjects_json = { 'subjectlist': [
  { id: 0, text: 'Computer Graphics' },
  { id: 1, text: 'Automata Theory' },
  { id: 2, text: 'Programming in C' }
]};


var exams_json = { 'examlist': [
  { id: 0, text: 'IAT 1' },
  { id: 1, text: 'IAT 2' },
  { id: 2, text: 'Sem 2' }
 ]};

/*Contains definition of component item-subject... 
  Its method() contains call to exam component because it will be 
  called depending on the subject selected dynamically*/

Vue.component('item-subject', {
  props: ['item'],
  template: '<li v-on:click="showExams" class="subject-list-item">{{             
    item.text }}</li>',
   methods: {
    showExams: function(){    
      // alert(this.item.text)
      console.log("Subject Clicked: "+this.item.text)
      var app2 = new Vue({
        el: '#app-2',
        data:  exams_json,
            methods: {
             showStudents: function(){       
             console.log("exams  rendered")
          }
        }
      })
    },   
  }  
});


//Contains definition of component item-exam.

Vue.component('item-exam', {
  props: ['item'],
  template: '<li v-on:click="showStudents" class="exam-list-item">{{ item.text }}</li>',
   methods: {
    showStudents: function(){    
      alert(this.item.text)
      console.log("exam component executed") 
      // console.log("Exam Clicked: "+this.item)   
    }
  }  
});

//Call to subject component
var app1 = new Vue({
  el: '#app-1',
  data:  subjects_json,
  methods: {
    showExams: function(){
      console.log("subjects rendered")
    }
  }
})
```

So what this code does is, when i click on the first list i.e. subjects list, it dynamically renders new exams list.
Now when i click on second list, alert() method is called successfully.
However if i click any of the subject list(first list), now the alert() is not triggered while clicking second list.
Please tell me whats wrong.

Comment: It seems you're creating multiple Vue instances. You don't need more than one and you don't need to target multiple elements with `el`. Your component tags should take care of how to render what. My guess is that creating a new Vue instance within another is creating the problem. You should also consider single file components. It makes the code more organized and debugging becomes easier.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I am a beginner in Vue so dont have much idea. Actually every time the user clicks on a subject, different number of items will be obtained. So how to update the component with new values?

Comment: Create one Vue instance with `new Vue()`. Separately create the components. Now add these components to the Vue instance with `Vue.component()`. Make sure the components have their relevant data, methods, etc within their scope.

Comment: Thanks @ba_ul, i didn't know we just have to create a single Vue instance. I'll try it and get back. Also can you provide any links which shows how to update the data which is received by props. I'm provinding json objects to props which may change everytime. So i need to re-render the component multiple times.

Comment: I'm not totally clear what you're trying to do. Have you checked the official guide https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Props? It can be a little confusing, so study it carefully. The idea is this: the child component needs to update when something changes in the parent component. For this to happen, the child component needs to declare a prop. This is an excellent guide: https://css-tricks.com/intro-to-vue-2-components-props-slots/

Comment: @ba_ul Thanks for the link.. I'll refer it for further development.